# How do I summarize calculations on many random samples in one dataframe?

Tags: r

In R, I would like to automate the asymptote analysis of the home range area of an animal.
The idea is to graphically visualize the point at which you've collected enough observations of the animal for home range area to stabilize - i.e. reach an asymptote.  For this I need to take many random samples of my dataset at increasing sample sizes in order to generate a curve with error bars.

Here's the procedure I'd like to automate: Lets say dataset has n observations (n = 10 in the dataset below; typical is more like n = 100).
For each integer x from 5 to n, take x random pts from the dataset (with replacement) and calculate the home range size 100 times. The output dataframe should be 100 rows and n-5 columns, each containing a home range estimate.

a small sample (10 rows) of the datset looks like this:

```
a<- c(189007.8, 1997503,    9.0)
b<- c(189008.9, 1997521,    7.0)
c<- c(189013.6, 1997521,    8.0)
d<- c(189013.4, 1997513,    8.0)
e<- c(189026.4, 1997509,    12.0)
f<- c(189038.5, 1997527,    7.5)
g<- c(189024.1, 1997520,    8.0)
h<- c(189017.5, 1997498,    5.5)
i<- c(189040.6, 1997501,    7.0)
j<- c(189014.6, 1997488,    10.0)
dataset<-data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j))
colnames(dataset)<-c("X","Y","Z")
```

and this is how I calculate home range size (i.e. Vol95)

```
library("ks")
library("KernSmooth")
Ha <- Hpi(dataset)
minX<-min(dataset$X)-25
minY<-min(dataset$Y)-25
minZ<-0
maxX<-max(dataset$X)+25
maxY<-max(dataset$Y)+25
maxZ<-max(dataset$Z)+5
fhata <- kde(x=dataset, H=Ha, gridsize=151, binned=FALSE, xmin=c(minX,minY,minZ),
             xmax=c(maxX,maxY,maxZ))
Vol95<-contourSizes(fhata, cont=95)
```

I would like to automate this procedure so as to eliminate the tedious copying and pasting. I suspect that this involves a nested for loop, but I am too much of a programming novice to make it work. Help appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not run as given: minX, maxX, etc. are not defined (although I can guess what they are meant to be). Also, please explain what you mean by `calculate the home range size 100 times`. For a given (random) subset of your `dataset` running your code repeatedly gives the same result??

Comment: @jlhoward: I fixed the code: sorry about that - I cut the min/max part to simplify, but I think I over-simplified.  Since you're sampling randomly from the dataset, you get a slightly different result each of the 100 times that you run the home range analysis.  Each of those 100 runs would be a different row in a first column in the dataset, then as you increase the sample size above n = 5, you'd fill in an additional column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Data
dataset = structure(
  list(X = c(189007.8, 189008.9, 189013.6, 189013.4, 189026.4, 189038.5, 189024.1, 189017.5, 189040.6, 189014.6), 
    Y = c(1997503, 1997521, 1997521, 1997513, 1997509, 1997527, 1997520, 1997498, 1997501, 1997488), 
    Z = c(9, 7, 8, 8, 12, 7.5, 8, 5.5, 7, 10)), 
  .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
  row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 
  class = "data.frame")

# Processing
set.seed(0)
Vol95 = matrix(0, nrow=100, ncol=nrow(dataset)-4)
for (x in 5:nrow(dataset)) {
  for (k in 1:nrow(Vol95)) {
    rows <- sample.int(nrow(dataset), x) 
    Ha <- Hpi(dataset[rows,])
    fhata <- kde(x=dataset[rows,], H=Ha, gridsize=151, binned=FALSE)
    Vol95[k,x-4] <- contourSizes(fhata, cont=95)
  }
}
```